# How to get real time data update for my view with expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I want to set up a dynamic page (without reloading my page),

in first, i want to render my dashboard view, then when i get an update in my DB (update from another user), i want my rendered dashboard to update the data displayed in realtime with [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/).

I am a beginner with websocket and i tried to use [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws), but it seems that i need to put in my rendered dashboard page a `<script></script>` with a message to trigger the socket from express-ws every time i want new data from my DB.

So, does there is a more elegant way to subscribe to my dashboard data update from my DB without to do a `setInterval` from the client side ? (In Angular 6, i know that you can use `Subscribe/Observables` to do the trick, but i don't know any equivalent in expressjs)

Dashboard view (engine = ejs):

```html
<% include ../header.ejs %>
...
<% locals.dataDashboard.forEach((dashboard) => { %>
<div id="collapsable" class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="username" class="row"  >
            <a href="/profile/<%= dashboard.USERNAME %>">@<%= dashboard.USERNAME %></a>
        </div>
        <div id="comment" class="row"  >
            <%= dashboard.COMMENT %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% }); %>
...
<% include ../footer.ejs %>
```

API route:

```
app.ws('/dashboard', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('connexion', (msg) => {
      log.debug('api.get(/dashboard)');
      return db.getDashboard()
          .then((dashboard) => {
            // return ws.render('pages/dashboard', dashboard);
            return ws.send(dashboard);
          })
          .catch((err) => { log.error(err); });
    });
});
```

Also, i don't seem to be able to render and bind a websocket in one go in my route (that would be more convenient than to render my dashboard then create my websocket)

PS: Does websocket is really the solution here ? (i feel a bit stuck with this kind of solution)

Comment: what is error stack?

Comment: webSocket connections must be initiated by the client (from the browser) so you cannot start them in a route handler on the server.  You must start them from a `<script> in the web page.  You also don't create connection listeners inside a route handler because that adds a new connection listener every time a client hits that route.  You create the connection listeners outside the route in the code right after you create your websocket server.

Comment: @jfriend00 So, i have no other choise but to render my page then do an eventEmitter from the client side (with a setInterval) ? If so, does i need to update my data manually (overwritting all my dynamic var in my view with jquery) ?

Comment: @SagarRanaMagar No error, that's just the code that i could get so far.

Comment: You can create a webSocket or socket.io connection from the webpage and then the server can send data over that to the web page whenever it wants.  When the webpage receives the data, it then inserts it into the web page.

Comment: @jfriend00 have you an exemple ?